# Privileges page percentage alignment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

On the privileges page there percentages are miss-aligned.

[image: screenshot]

I'm on a mac using the latest stable chrome build.

Comment: I can reproduce on mac safari

Comment: Same on windows using IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera

Comment: I'm looking into this

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on FireFox 6.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.7, while I can reproduce it on Safari 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

The privileges page has been completely redesigned since this was posted.